# AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission not showing dialog

Tags: ios, ios9, avaudiosession

I'm trying to record audio in a project I inherited. All used to work fine, until iOS 9. It seems now requestRecordPermission calls it's block with false without displaying a dialog. When I check for the current permission, before requesting it, I always get Undetermined. Even on subsequent runs of the app without a reset.

I'm testing on an actual device, and resetting the permissions (settings->general->reset->reset location and privacy) each time.
Also my app does not show in settings->privacy->microphone, but does show in the general app's list, where I can see the other permissions it uses but no microphone.

Is there some project setting that can affect it? It seems like the os does not understand that I ask for the permission, hence no dialog and no listing in the permissions.

code:

```
AVAudioSessionRecordPermission permissionStatus = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] recordPermission];    
switch (permissionStatus) {
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined:
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
            if (granted) {
                NSLog(@"req granted");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"req denied");
            }
        }];
        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied:
        NSLog(@"denied");
        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted:
        NSLog(@"granted");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

this is in AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. On every run (first after reset as well as subsequent), the first check returns undetermined, and then requestRecordPermission calls it's block with granted=false without displaying a dialog.

Comment: Excellent. Could you show log results too? Also, where is this code running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the "Bundle display name" (basically the name of your app)  in the "Info.plist" will fix the problem.

Comment: Dude, how did you figure that out? That is so random.

Comment: Deleted comment

Answer (score 0):

As stated [in the doc here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616601-requestrecordpermission), this value will be static once the user took a decision for an app, even if you have the "Bundle display name" set as proposed in 2015 by Guitz.

Only the user can reset this decision:

> Tip
>   When a user responds to a recording permission prompt for your app, the system remembers the choice. If the user has denied recording permission, **they can reenable it in Settings > Privacy > Microphone.**

I have implemented a message for the user to turn on the microphone in the settings when they try to record and the permission is denied for the app.